# How do I $_GET correct ID

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

picture.php

```
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    header('location:/');
    exit();
} else if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    print_r($_GET);
}
```

$_GET output

```
 Array ( [page] => picture )
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/picture/?$ /picture/?id=$1 [L]
```

URL format : `http://local.com/42/picture/`

Question : How to make the `$_GET['id']` will print **`42`** and not the `picture`

Comment: Got it & my fault. It should be `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/picture/$ /index.php?page=picture&id=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *L* flag causes a re-injection of the already rewritten URL into the rewriting process. So when `/42/picture/` gets rewritten to `/picture/?id=42` it then gets rewritten to `/index.php?page=picture`.

You can avoid this by putting a rule in front of your other rules that stops the rewriting process for every request that’s path can be mapped onto an existing file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILNAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: Accepted answer for additional info.

Answer (score 1):

From the output of your `var_dump`, it seems the first rule is matching and not the second. The order you write rules matters, you should probably revert the two rules. Since your first rule is shorter.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/picture/?$ /picture/?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

You can take a look at the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for your reference.